# Hardware virtualization support for Core i7 + P55

Tags: virtualization, multi-core

I'm considering a hardware upgrade from AMD Opteron 1216 to a Core i7 920 or Core i7 860. I want to know if Hardware Virtualization (VT-X) is supported? I found the spec sheets online which say yes. However, I'm concerned that it might be supported under certain chipsets/mobo combinations only.

Why I have this concern is because the Xeon motherboards claim to support hardware virtualization but not the spec sheets for the P55 based chipsets....so..any suggestions?

Also, is it possible for a LGA 1156 Xeon to be used on a P55 chipset mobo without loss of any functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Hardware virtualization depends only on CPU model. You may check VT-x support in your CPU at http://ark.intel.com/ . As far as I remember, all i7 family has VT-x.

Comment: This is not entirely true - Hardware Virtualization can be disabled via the BIOS on a number of systems that I've worked on so BIOS support is required and this will depend on the chipset. At least one vendor (Sony) have released laptops where the CPU supports Vt-x but the BIOS does not, preventing the use of software that requires hardware virualization support - in the Sony case they have subsequently fixed the problem - see Wikipedia article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_VAIO_Z_series

Comment: well, it's a Sony :)

Comment: Yeah..this is why I raised the question. Are there any desktop motherboards from Intel/Asus/MSI which restrict VT-X through the BIOS?

Comment: In my experience - no. they always put award/ami/other popular bios (Intel has own) while laptop vendors usually always have own boards and own bios for it. Sony decided to remove VT-x option because they were afraid of the mysterious trojans which can quietly run in the separate cpu/mem space. as soon as VT-x is available many years and there are still no real trojans which can work in this way, as you see, Sony enabled it again.